# Coin Change understanding for a DP solution

Tags: java

I have an exercise:

> "You are given coins of different denominations and a total amount of money amount. Write a function to compute the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1."
>
> Example 1:

```
     coins = [1, 2, 5], amount = 11
     return 3 (11 = 5 + 5 + 1)
```

And I also googled a solution like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        int dp[] = new int[amount + 1];
        final int INF = 0x7ffffffe;
        for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) dp[i] = INF;
        for (int i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < coins.length; j++) {
                if (i + coins[j] <= amount)
                    dp[i + coins[j]] = Math.min(dp[i + coins[j]], dp[i] + 1);
            }
        }
        return dp[amount] == INF ? -1 : dp[amount];
    }
}
```

I know its about DP, however, I am so confusing about it, like, what's the meaning of `dp[i + coins[j]]`, why add `i`, and why `dp[i] + 1`, why add 1?

Can anyone show the way out in simple English?

Comment: Did you understand what the `dp` array stores ? If you understand this, the algorithm is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Your instructor wants you to write the solution from scratch, not to Google for a solution. That way you might *learn* something.

Comment: It depresses me that this question got 4 up votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so let's first look at what that code is doing and what it's using. DP is used to store the amount of coins required for a certain value. It's doing it ordered so to get the amount of coins needed for a value is just the "valueth entry of dp". But how do we get that ordered list of amounts?

He's itertating over all coins he has using the inner for loop, trying to add the value of the coin to the current value (i). If that's smaller than the target amount he'll assign a value to it.

```
dp[i + coins[j]] = (...)
```

As we know that our list is ordered by the value we'll get the value of the entry we need to change by taking the value of our current entry (i) plus the value of the current coin (coins[j]). That is the left part of it.

Now for the right part: You're looking for the smallest amount possible so you're using a Math.Min to get the lesser of n arguments, in that case two. The first argument is the value we're about to override. If we already found a really good way to represent a value, why override it? We could accidentally kill it so we make sure that we only do so if we found a solution that's NOT BETTER than what we got. The 2nd argument is just the amount of coins we need to get to the current value + 1.

```
(...) = Math.min(dp[i + coins[j]], dp[i] + 1);
```

If you haven't quite understood it yet feel free to ask for further details :)

Comment: Thx! So in most cases,  "dp[i] + 1" will be the value of "dp[i + coins[j]]"? And so, if I understand right, the program actually lists all the possibility for the coins combinations that have value below amount?

Comment: Yep it will first calculate all possible values and their best solutions to finally find the best solution for your value. It's called a greedy algorithm and it's a really inefficient one.

Comment: Accidentally hit enter twice, so another comment it is. "dpi[i] + 1" and dpi[i + coins[j]]" don't need to be the same. It's just there to check for the BETTER of those two ways. It might be that you already found a good way and you don't want to loose that value so you go and just take the better of those two options as both are possible :)

Comment: Nice answers! Thank you!